# Using XWPFParagraph and XWPFRun, how to make the lines printing on the same. See the description please

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I'm generating a .docx file from Java using Apache POI.
I'm having a table that has columns like..
[table without any entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzwdj.png)
I'm writing the content inside second row using following code.

```
String itemNames[] = {“Item 1”, “Item Name 2”, "Item 3"};
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
 //getRow(1) represents second row of the table
 //printing sr. no
 paragraph = table.getRow(1).getCell(0).addParagraph();
 paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
 paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
 run = paragraph.createRun();
 run.setText(i+1);

//printing item names
paragraph = table.getRow(1).getCell(1).addParagraph();
paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setText(itemNames[i]);

//printing qty
paragraph = table.getRow(1).getCell(2).addParagraph();
paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setText(1 + (i*10));
}
```

That is generating the output like below.
[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KwPx.png)
In this, as you can see, the item name for row 2 can't be written in 1 line as cell width is smaller than the content. So, there's word wrap set so that line completes writing in 2 lines. However, rest of the content take only 1 line.

So when the code is printing third entry, it is creating a new paragraph in sr no, item name and qty and writing the values. But, as you can see in the image, the output is not as it should be.

I tried to get number of lines in paragraph and in run also but I could not get the actual number and as the item name is bigger, I want to add breaks to other columns to save it in proper form. But how to find the line numbers for every run for the cell 2 in row 2?

Comment: Why not creating a new table row for each i > 0?

Comment: Thank you sir for that suggestion. I want to try it but as of now I've not implemented it like for more tables. I saw a method to add table inside cell in the documentation, should I try that approach? Or there's some better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is writing the content of row 2 of the table into the already present row and then for each further content row, creating a new `XWPFTableRow` using [XWPFTable.createRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html#createRow--).

Example:

First table in `WordTableExample.docx`:

[image]

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordInsertTableRows {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordTableExample.docx"));
  XWPFTable table = doc.getTableArray(0);
  XWPFTableRow row;
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;

  String itemNames[] = {"Item 1", "Item Name 2", "Item 3"};

  for(int i=0; i<itemNames.length; i++) {
   row = table.getRow(1+i); //getRow(1) represents second row of the table
   if (row == null) row = table.createRow(); //if there is not a row already, then create one
   //printing sr. no
   paragraph = row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0);
   if (paragraph == null) paragraph = row.getCell(0).addParagraph();
   paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
   //paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER); //this sets valign for the paragraph
   row.getCell(0).setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER); //I suspect you wants set valign for the cell
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText(""+(i+1));

   //printing item names
   paragraph = row.getCell(1).getParagraphArray(0);
   if (paragraph == null) paragraph = row.getCell(1).addParagraph();
   paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
   //paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
   row.getCell(1).setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText(itemNames[i]);

   //printing qty
   paragraph = row.getCell(2).getParagraphArray(0);
   if (paragraph == null) paragraph = row.getCell(2).addParagraph();
   //paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
   row.getCell(2).setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText(""+(1 + (i*10)));
  }

  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("WordTableExampleNew.docx"));

  doc.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It gave the perfect result. Thank you very much for providing this solution and that too quick..